# Clean way to free double pointer in c

Tags: c, buffer, free

I am dynamically allocating a double pointer (char **pointer), some methods later the information about the length is no longer known.

Is there a clean way to free both the "pointer array" and the "char array"s, without knowing the length of the pointer array?

Comment: If you don't know the length, then you did something wrong.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know, that having the exact length is the "correct" way, but I am explicitly asking if a different way is possible.

Comment: A different way is to have a linked list.

Comment: If you prepared the list with a terminating NULL pointer (assuming the list should have no entries that would otherwise be NULL), then you can enumerate it, freeing each pointer until you reach the NULL, then free the list itself. It would work, but it's dreadfully brittle. In reality, you should be toting around a `struct S { char ** lst; size_t len; };` instead of just a naked pointer. To that end, how does the code that you're *giving* just your pointer to actually use it? Surely you provide some mechanism for *them* to know how long it is. Why don't you just use that (whatever it is) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig thx, I got it :) It was no based on a real "case", I just wanted to unterstand/know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's technically a way.

If you allocate one extra pointer, and set the last one to `NULL`, you can free all of the double arrays and then the double array array by freeing until you reach `NULL`. It's a similar principle to strings.

You shouldn't probably need this, though.

Comment: As I said in general comments, this *can* work, but is woefully brittle in that it restricts the "list" to no longer allow `NULL` values within as valid entries (since `NULL` is now assumed to be the end-of-list marker). Use it, but know what you're doing. Ideally you use a structure that contains both the list pointer and its length coupled together.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of using perhaps index 0 of the array as the total length of it.